# Dataproc - Pyspark - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - although the dependency jars are in the classpath

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running PySpark application on Dataproc cluster.

The dependency jars are in a cloud storage bucket.

While creating the cluster I've set the `"spark.jars"` property to point to the `"gs://"` path of the jars in cloud storage. In SparkUI for the application, I could see the dependency jars under ClassPath entries. But the Spark application fails with "`ClassNotFoundException`".

Alternatively I've tried to submit the job using `"gcloud dataproc"` cli command and passed the jars using `"--jars" flag`. Still I get the same error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is the exception from driver or executor?